# Cannot boot ubuntu 15.10 from Samsung 950 Pro PCIe NVME SSD

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, 15.10, ssd

I just installed desktop 15.10 but met the same problem described here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309056

ubuntu is installed on /dev/nvme0n1p2 ~ /dev/nvme0n1p5, which is not recognized by gparted

I tried the boot-repair method but it told me "An error occurred during the repair." when it finished running and it still couldn't boot. It sometimes ran into no such device error and booted into a grub cmd like this -

```
> error: no such device: .......  
grub rescue>
```

I have windows 10 installed on another disk. 950 pro is an empty disk. I tried both automatic install (remove everything on the disk) and manual partition(something else). Can somebody plz help?

See [detailed error info here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15907401/)

Comment: If using gparted, be sure to download the newest version: gparted should be at least version 0.24.0-1 to recognize NVMe devices
http://gparted.sourceforge.net/index.php
 Since 16.04 will be out in a couple of days have you tried it?

Comment: What @oldfred said. You have the absolute cutting edge hardware. Use 16.04.

Comment: @oldfred when exactly is it coming out

Comment: I have been running the daily since Feb. on a new Skylake build as 15.10would not support it well. Sometime April 21. May depend on your time zone: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule  See also: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes

Comment: @oldfred thx. could you post your answer here so I can give the points to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With cutting edge hardware, you need the newest versions of software, and sometimes even ppa's to get newer than in standard distributions.

If using gparted, be sure to download the newest version: gparted should be at least version 0.24.0-1 to recognize NVMe devices

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/index.php

Since 16.04 is now released.But be sure to review release notes:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes

http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

Answer (score 0):

You can burn ubuntu 15.10 in a pen drive and load it up during boot. Start installation, and you will get an option to "remove 15.10 and install it again", select that option and continue. This should resolve your problem!